# Goal Funnel and external sites

Tags: google-analytics, goal-tracking

I have a destination goal set to a thank-you page, and I want to know how many of those goals completions come directly from my site's homepage, however, before getting to the thank-you page, the user has to visit a page on an external domain, which then redirects back to the thank-you page on my site (where the goal is completed).

I can view a Goal Funnel report and see how many goals come from "/", but I'm concerned that having the intermediate step on an external domain may be screwing up those results somehow.

Are my concerns completely unfounded?